# How do I fix the "undefined variable" and "database" error while installing the PHP imageboard script "Futallaby"

Tags: php

I am trying to set up a futaba imageboard using the "Futallaby" PHP script available at [1chan.](http://www.1chan.net/futallaby/index_old.html) I am running the PHP script using XAMPP on my MacBook, and am able to access the main page. However when I click the [Manage] tab some errors appear above the manage control panel.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: upfile_name in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/imgboard/strings_e.php on line 42
Database error, check SQL settings
show tables like 'ochanlog'
ochanlogCreating table!
\ncreate table ochanlog (primary key(no), no int not null auto_increment, now text, name text, email text, sub text, com text, host text, pwd text, ext text, w int, h int, tim text, time int, md5 text, fsize int, root timestamp, resto int)
Unable to create table!

Notice: Undefined variable: pass in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/imgboard/imgboard.php on line 917

Notice: Undefined variable: titlebar in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/imgboard/imgboard.php on line 270
```

I was able to fix some of the errors that were there, by replacing

```
$upfile_name=$_FILES["upfile"]["name"];
$upfile=$_FILES["upfile"]["tmp_name"];
```

with

```
$upfile_name = isset ( $_FILES [ "upfile" ][ "name" ])? $_FILES [ "upfile" ][ "name" ]: '' ; 
$upfile = isset ( $_FILES [ "upfile" ][ "tmp_name" ])? $_FILES [ "upfile" ][ "tmp_name" ]: '' ;
```

in "imgboard.php".

This is my first time using PHP and I was able to fix that problem using Google, however I cannot find the fixes for the errors mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code at the top of your script to stop showing the notices:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

As for the database error check the mysql settings and connection credentials.